# Multiple text file processing using scan

Tags: r, text-files

I have this code that works for me (it's from Jockers' Text Analysis with R for Students of Literature). However, what I need to be able to do is to automate this: I need to perform the "ProcessingSection" for up to thirty individual text files. How can I do this? Can I have a table or data frame that contains thirty occurrences of "text.v" for each `scan("*.txt")`?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
# Chapter 5 Start up code

setwd("D:/work/cpd/R/Projects/5/")

text.v <- scan("pupil-14.txt", what="character", sep="\n")
length(text.v)


#ProcessingSection
text.lower.v <- tolower(text.v)
mars.words.l <- strsplit(text.lower.v, "\\W")
mars.word.v <- unlist(mars.words.l)

#remove blanks
not.blanks.v <- which(mars.word.v!="")
not.blanks.v

#create a new vector to store the individual words
mars.word.v <- mars.word.v[not.blanks.v]
mars.word.v
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help as your example is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Admitting you're happy with the result of `mars.word.v`,
you can turn this portion of code into a function that will accept a single argument,
the result of scan.

```
processing_section <- function(x){
  unlist(strsplit(tolower(x), "\\W"))
}
```

Then, if all `.txt` files are in the current working directory, you should be able to list them, 
and apply this function with:

```
lf <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
lapply(lf, function(path) processing_section(scan(path, what="character", sep="\n")))
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. Would it be easier to have a function return a table or dataframe (sorry - newbie) containing a list of text.v types? (i.e. a list of vectors returned from the scanning of multiple .txt files and then I access each 'text.v' using a subscript on that list or dataframe of vectors?

Comment: Depends of what you want to do but not sure to understand your question.

Comment: I really appreciate this, Vincent. Can I read in a number of text files - students stories - and aftrr each one is read in by the scan() each text file is stored in a vector and a list/table of vectors containing the contents of the text files is returned as a table or list of vectors

Comment: Amazing - you make it look so simple. Thank you. I am hoping to begin Doctorate in Education - I'm interested in English Language use - spoken and written - when pupils (13-14 year old) use a multi-user simulation program to learn and write about Science. I thank you on their behalf!